# Can i integrate multiple lists in python?

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can I iterate through two lists in parallel in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python)

i have 3 lists like this:

```
name = ['sam', 'john', 'napoleon', 'tanaka', 'ming']
country = ['USA', 'England', 'France', 'Japan', 'China']
age = [23, 41, 19, 16, 55]
```

and i want an output like:

```
sam; USA; 23
john; England; 41
napoleon; France; 19
tanaka; Japan; 16
ming; China; 55
```

any help would be great.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `zip()`:

```
name = ['sam', 'john', 'napoleon', 'tanaka', 'ming']
country = ['USA', 'England', 'France', 'Japan', 'China']
age = [23, 41, 19, 16, 55]
for x,y,z in zip(name,country,age):
    print("{0}; {1}; {2}".format(x,y,z))
```

or use `map()`:

```
mapp=map(lambda x,y,z:"; ".join((x,y,str(z))),name,country,age)
for x in mapp:
    print(x)
```

**output:**

```
sam; USA; 23
john; England; 41
napoleon; France; 19
tanaka; Japan; 16
ming; China; 55
```

Comment: I had an answer, but this one is better. Thanks for the tip on zip!

Comment: Possibly neater: `map("; ".join, names, countries, map(str, ages))`

Answer (score 3):

```
name = "sam john napoleon tanaka ming".split()
country = "USA England France Japan China".split()
age = [23, 41, 19, 16, 55]

print "\n".join(["%s; %s %d" % (x) for x in zip(name,country,age)])
```

Comment: +1 for one liner, use `format()` instead of these old `%s` formatting.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary actually `%s` is still totally credable

Comment: @JakobBowyer but it's good to use `format()` as the old style formatting might get deprecated.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary might is a big thing in language design

Comment: @JakobBowyer PEP 3101: Advanced String Formatting. Note: the 2.6 description `mentions the format() method for both 8-bit and Unicode strings. In 3.0, only the str type (text strings with Unicode support) supports this method; the bytes type does not. The plan is to eventually make this the only API for string formatting, and to start deprecating the % operator in Python 3.1.` source :[What’s New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html), so it's better if we suggest using `format`.

Comment: Its still gonna be around for a long long time

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the lists are the same length:

```
for i in range(len(name)):
    print '%s; %s; %s' %(name[i], country[i], age[i])
```

UPDATE: This assumes you're using Python 3.x. For 2.x, use xrange for general performance improvement. Alternatively:

```
for i in range(len(name)):
    print '{0}; {1}; {2}'.format{name[i], country[i], age[i]}
```

Comment: `range(len(name))` is expensive.

Comment: @jakob: do you have to pay for it? <:P

Comment: @DSeita use `xrange()` on python 2.x and `range()` on python 3.x and use `format()` for formatting strings instead of old style(`%s`) formatting.

Comment: `range(len(name))` is still a bad idea!, just do `for pos, i in enumerate(name)`

Answer (score 0):

If you know they will all have the same length, then you can do:

```
name = ['sam', 'john', 'napoleon', 'tanaka', 'ming']
country = ['USA', 'England', 'France', 'Japan', 'China']
age = [23, 41, 19, 16, 55]

i = 0

for n in name:
    print name[i] + '; ' + country[i] + '; ' + str(age[i])
    i++
```

Comment: better use `xrange(len(name))` instead of manually increasing `i`.

Comment: very true, I think D Seitas answer is my favorite way

Comment: ... or use `for i, n in enumerate(name): ...`

Comment: i++ ? python 2.x doesnt have a ++ operator

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents ;-)

Using a generator from the itertools module:

```
from itertools import izip

nlist = ['%s; %s; %s' %t for t in izip(name, country, age)]
```

Comment: two problems - missing closing square bracket ... and you can't join an int to a string  :)

Comment: so true - you should always try to run your own code ;-)